# FreeIPA: External DNS requests (google etc.) fail for clients on new subnet

Tags: domain-name-system, freeipa

I'm trying to rebuild my home network to make use of FreeIPA to manage some Linux clients.  This has all gone well on my main network (192.168.222.0/24) with all clients being able to resolve both internal DNS and external requests for google etc.  All clients on that network can SSH (with sudo) using a user I created in FreeIPA.

The issue comes when I try to connect my Wifi network (192.168.30.0/24) to the FreeIPA server.  Clients on the Wifi network can only resolve internal DNS.  Requests for google.com etc. are ignored.  This works fine on my main network.

So from a host on my main 192.168.222.0/24 network:

```
[root@kvm ~]# dig @auth.brocas.home monitoring.brocas.home +short
192.168.222.130
[root@kvm ~]# dig @auth.brocas.home  google.com +short
172.217.169.78
```

But on my 192.168.30.0/24 network, no external DNS requests are resolved:

```
[manjaro-i3 ~]# dig @auth.brocas.home monitoring.brocas.home  +short
192.168.222.130
[manjaro-i3 ~]# dig @auth.brocas.home  google.com +short
[manjaro-i3 ~]#
```

Does anyone know why this might be?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what do the logs in the dns server tell you? If I recall correctly, the "allow-recursion" directive is set to "localnets; localhost;", so you need to create anothere trusted nework bind acl

Comment: Can you show your network topology?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks natxo - looks like that was it!

Edited `/etc/named/ipa-ext.conf` like so:

```
acl "trusted_network" {
  127.0.0.1;
  192.168.222.0/24;
  192.168.30.0/24;
};
```

And added the `allow-recursion` section to `/etc/named/ipa-options-ext.conf`:

```
/* turns on IPv6 for port 53, IPv4 is on by default for all ifaces */
listen-on-v6 { any; };

/* dnssec-enable is obsolete and 'yes' by default */
dnssec-validation yes;

allow-recursion { trusted_network; };
```

Then I just restarted the FreeIPA services:

```
[root@auth ~]# ipactl restart
```

Now everything works!  Thanks!